# GWT Celltable : Custom DatePickerCell

Tags: gwt, datepicker, uidatepicker, gwt-2.2-celltable

I want to use `customDatePickerCell` in `CellTable`.

Current GWT2.3 `Datepicker` cell is as follows

[image: GWT DatePickerCell]

I am using GWT 2.3.  `DatePicker` cell showing Navigation only for month not for year
also there is no seprate navigation for month and Year.

Is there any way to create `CustomDatePickercell` as follows or close to this

[image: Custom DatePickerCell]

1. Separate navigation for year and month
2. Sequence of days like S M T W T F S

Any one developed such datepicker cell. if yes then share sample code else provide hint for the same.

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'll copy/paste here the [answer I made on the GWT Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/1HPnHWSrcXY/Toq83_lfsGgJ):

I haven't tried it but theoretically you should be able to implement your own MonthSelector with separate navigation for month and year.

As for the first day of week, it depends on the locale (see [CalendarUtil#getStartingDayOfWeek()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html#getStartingDayOfWeek%28%29) and [DateTimeFormatInfo#firstDayOfTheWeek()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormatInfo.html#firstDayOfTheWeek%28%29))